# How can I delete empty hash entires?

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out how to delete a hash entry that returns a value of `{}`.

I was working with something like this;

```
if (ref($snapshots{"ID\:$id"}) eq "{}") {
    print "ID $id hash no snapshots\n";
}
```

It does not appear to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I escape the `:` because.... I thought I had to, I assume I don't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given `{}`, `ref` will be `"HASH"` not `"{}"`

```
if (ref $snapshots{"ID\:$id"} eq 'HASH' && !scalar keys %{$snapshots{"ID\:$id"}}) {
    delete $snapshots{"ID\:$id"};
}
```

Comment: What does the `!scalar ...` do?

Comment: @Solignis: It's parsed as `!scalar(keys(%{$snapshots{"ID\:$id"}}))`. `keys` returns the list of keys, which in a scalar context turns into the number of keys. The negation is true if the number of keys is 0, i.e. if the hash is empty.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation, I don't like using code that I don't understand.

Comment: It tests that the hash is empty. In list context `keys` returns the hash's keys by forcing to scalar context, you get its amounts of elements. Then it tests that is not not-false, that is here, not different than 0 (same as `… && (scalar keys %{$snapshots{"ID\:$id"}} == 0)`

Comment: You don't have to use `keys`. The hash itself evaluates to a false value in scalar context if it is empty. So `%{ $snapshot{"ID\:$id"} }` is sufficient to test for empty-ness.

Comment: Perfect, everything works exactly like I wanted it. Thanks for all the help.